# What to escape XSS (JSTL)

Tags: jstl, xss, cout

I'm working on a small JSTL project and I want to prevent xss, the first step I want to take is escaping in html.

Is there a rule what I should escape and what not?
For example the following code prints out a form from the databasepoints

```
<c:forEach var="player" items="${players}" varStatus="counter">
<li>
<label for="<c:out value="${counter.count}"/>" >${player.email}:</label>
<input class="values" id="<c:out value="${counter.count}"/>" type="number" name="<c:out value="${player.id}"/>" ondblclick="fillInInput(this)" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<c:out value="${player.points}"/>">
</li>
</c:forEach>
```

This prints some error messages:

```
<c:if test="${errors.size() >0}">
    <div id="errors">
        <c:forEach var="error" items="${errors}">
            <p><c:out value="${error}"/></p>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

This prints a list with rewards from the database

```
<c:forEach var="reward" items="${rewards}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${reward.name}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

This prints a checkbox list with rewardtypes which the user can choose from:

```
<c:forEach var="reward" items="${rewards}" varStatus="counter">
    <li><input id="<c:out value="${counter.count + 100}"/>" class="rewards" type="checkbox" onchange="checkButton('button2','rewards')" name="rewardType" value="<c:out value="${reward}"/>" checked>
    <label for="<c:out value="${counter.count + 100}"/>"><c:out value="${reward}"/></label></li>
    </c:forEach>
```

Right now I've simply escaped everything,but it doesn't feel right. Can anyone tell me if there is some rule or something so I know what I should escape and what not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything that comes from user input, unless you completely trust the user

Comment: So only text input fields? Or also checkboxes? You know good software to test if my website is xss safe?

Comment: Checkboxes come from user input in html, and users can edit the html to submit whatever they want. But your app may coerce that into a safe type, like Boolean.

Comment: So generatd error messages shouldn't be escaped?

Comment: You can, but you probably don't need to.

Comment: okay thank you. in one page I redirect to a page if there are any errors and i pass the error message in the url. In the page I redirect to I extract the errors. Should I escape there? I think I should since a user could maybe insert some javascript code inside the url.

Comment: No no no! That's user input!

Comment: Someone can send someone else a link to that page with an xss in the url. That is user input, even if by default, you are the user setting it.

Comment: So yes? I should escape it, like I thought ?

Comment: But if I load a list from a databae and print it out on a page, I shouldn't escape it, right?

Comment: Correct, since a user can't possibly affect that output.

Comment: @Bosiwow you should, unless *you* inserted all this data in the database and you're absolutely sure it doesn't contain any special character that needs to be escaped. If a user enters some data, and this data is stored in the db, and you later show this data, it's still user input and can contain anything. You seem to be thinking about performance before thinking about safety and correctness. You shouldn't. Escaping should be the default, and that's not what will cause performance troubles.

Comment: Hmm yeah, you're probably right, didn't think about that. So I should escape every jstl code? (Except maybe from the increasing id)